# TCP/IP and http diagramm deploiment

Tags: java, uml

I'm really stuck at diagram deploiment

I have a web browser that communicates with a server aplication via TCP / IP.

is that it changes anything when I change tcp / Ip  on http
knowing that the application is to use just at a local network in the company
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use http on a local network, I don't see the problem here.